# Day #2 of re-trying topology: Is the inner radius of an annulus used for a Mobius strip required exist to self intersect one?

Tags: general-topology, mobius-band

In this figure I circled half of the inner radius of a Mobius band that I used to construct a holed cross cap. I don't know if it is required to exist to do the self intersection because I read somewhere on this site that aside from the zip-pair construction the holed cross cap is also the limit as the inner radius used for the Mobius band approaches $0$.

My question is if that is true then does the limit of that Mobius band as the inner radius approaches $0$ still has an inner radius?

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: You're figure is somewhat unclear. It would have been better had you rendered it in 3D or drew a picture where one could see the diagram from all angles

Comment: The question title should have been more like: Real life experiment checking if Mobius band holed cross cap are equivalent

Comment: One last point, paper is not exact for seeing topological transformations. Say you roll paper into a cylinder then from the center of cylinder , each side will be stretched more than the other due to the thickness. Proof, let thickness of paper be $d$, then the surface area of outerside is given as $ 2\pi (r+d)$ while the inner side is $ 2\pi r$ where r is distance from axis of cylinder to a point on it

Comment: What's written is very much unclear, starting with lack of a definition of a "holed cross-cap." I also suggest you avoid notions such as "infinitesimally small."

Comment: The cross cap is just a particular way of putting the projective plane into three dimensional space, but it is pretty poorly behaved and not very good at developing intuition. Note there is a line of self-intersection which shouldn't really be considered as part of the structure. It is much easier to visualize non-orientable surfaces as quotient spaces of polygons.